# How do i convert tensorflow 2.0 estimator model to tensorflow lite?

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-lite

THe following code i have below produce the regular tensorflow model but when i try to convert it to tensorflow lite it doesn't work, i followed the following documentations.

[https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/linear[1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/linear)
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/get_started](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/get_started)

```
export_dir = "tmp"
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feat_cols))

estimator.export_saved_model(export_dir, serving_input_fn)

# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("tmp/1571728920/saved_model.pb")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dacorie Smith/PycharmProjects/JamaicaClassOneNotifableModels/ClassOneModels.py", line 208, in <module>
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
  File "C:\Users\Dacorie Smith\PycharmProjects\JamaicaClassOneNotifableModels\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\lite\python\lite.py", line 400, in convert
    raise ValueError("This converter can only convert a single "
ValueError: This converter can only convert a single ConcreteFunction. Converting multiple functions is under development.
```

Extract from Documentation

> TensorFlow Lite converter The TensorFlow Lite converter is a tool
>   available as a Python API that converts trained TensorFlow models into
>   the TensorFlow Lite format. It can also introduce optimizations, which
>   are covered in section 4, Optimize your model.
>
> The following example shows a TensorFlow SavedModel being converted
>   into the TensorFlow Lite format:
>
> import tensorflow as tf
>
> converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
>   tflite_model = converter.convert() open("converted_model.tflite",
>   "wb").write(tflite_model)

Comment: What is the error you received?

Comment: Do you get any error? What is the expected behavior, and what are you getting instead? Can you also include the link or preferably the extract of the documentation that you are referring to?

Comment: I add the error messages and more details to the question.

Comment: have you tried setting the saved model location like this: 
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("tmp/1571728920")
or like this:
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("./tmp/1571728920")

Comment: @JorgeJiménez i got the same error

Comment: I add the error messages and more details to the question @GuillermoGutiérrez

Comment: try this:
export_model = estimator.export_savedmodel('./tmp/', serving_input_receiver_fn)

and then: 
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("./tmp")
tflite_model = converter.convert()

I am not sure why your model is being saved in this folder: 1571728920

could you also shared the code of how are you creating the estimator

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a concrete function:

```
export_dir = "tmp"
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feat_cols))

estimator.export_saved_model(export_dir, serving_input_fn)

# Convert the model.
saved_model_obj = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir="tmp/1571728920/")
concrete_func = saved_model_obj.signatures['serving_default']

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])

# print(saved_model_obj.signatures.keys())
# converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
# converter.experimental_new_converter = True

tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

`serving_default` is the default key for signatures in a SavedModels.

If not working try to uncomment `converter.experimental_new_converter = True` and the two lines above it.

**Short explanation**

Based on [Concrete functions guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/concrete_function)

Eager execution in TensorFlow 2 evaluates operations immediately, without building graphs.
To save the model you need graph/s which is wrapped in a python callables: a concrete functions.