# error trying to conver tf model into tflite model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import lite


converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("C:/tmp")

model = converter.convert()

open("converted_model.lite", "wb").write(model)
```

it gives

```
ValueError: This converter can only convert a single ConcreteFunction. Converting multiple functions is under development.
```

Is there a way to fix this or converting my .pb model into a keras (h5) model???

Related questions: [How do i convert tensorflow 2.0 estimator model to tensorflow lite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58499146/11886026)

Comment: It will be helpful if you could share the code of the model which you are trying to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a concrete function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import lite


saved_model_obj = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir="C:/tmp")
concrete_func = saved_model_obj.signatures['serving_default']
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])

# print(saved_model_obj.signatures.keys())
# converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
# converter.experimental_new_converter = True

model = converter.convert()

open("converted_model.lite", "wb").write(model)
```

`serving_default` is the default key for signatures in a SavedModels.

If not working try to uncomment `converter.experimental_new_converter = True` and the two lines above it.

**Short explanation**

Based on [Concrete functions guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/concrete_function)

Eager execution in TensorFlow 2 evaluates operations immediately, without building graphs.
To save the model you need graph/s which is wrapped in a python callables: a concrete functions.