# Convert tensorflow 2.0 estimator to tensorflow lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-estimator

After exporting my saved_model.pb file, I would like to convert it in TfLite.

I had the same error than [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58499146/how-do-i-convert-tensorflow-2-0-estimator-model-to-tensorflow-lite?answertab=oldest#tab-top).
So I tried the proposed answer :

```py
import tensorflow as tf

export_dir = './saved/1587630121'

# Convert the model.
saved_model_obj = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir="saved/1587630121/")
concrete_func = saved_model_obj.signatures['serving_default']

#this line produce the error: ValueError: This converter can only convert a single
#ConcreteFunction. Converting multiple functions is under development. :
#converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
print(saved_model_obj.signatures.keys())
# converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
#converter.experimental_new_converter = True

tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

However, I have a new error:

Print Output:

```py
keysView(_SignatureMap({'predict': <tensorflow.python.eager.wrap_function.WrappedFunction     object at 0x7f6a9843cc90>, 
'classification':     <tensorflow.python.eager.wrap_function.WrappedFunction object at 0x7f6a981a6190>,
 'regression': <tensorflow.python.eager.wrap_function.WrappedFunction object at 0x7f6a74f78190>, 
'serving_default': <tensorflow.python.eager.wrap_function.WrappedFunction object at 0x7f6a74d020d0>}))
```

Output Error on converter.convert():

```py
Exception has occurred: ConverterError 
2020-04-23 12:05:52.644550: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20 
2020-04-23 12:05:52.644632: F tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:2690] 
Check failed: status.ok() 
Input_content string_val doesn't have the right dimensions for this string tensor   
 (while processing node 'head/AsString') 
Fatal Python error: Aborted

WARNING:tensorflow:Issue encountered when serializing variables.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. 
Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
to_proto not supported in EAGER mode.
```

Just in case, I exported with no issue my DNNclassifier estimator thanks to this code:

```py
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(self.feature_columns))
export_path = self.model_trained.export_saved_model(export_dir, serving_input_fn)
```

I am wondering if my error is because of a bad export of my .pb file, is it possible? Else do you have an idea to solve this error?

Thank you for your help.